# Change default keyboard android

Tags: android, methods, input, android-softkeyboard

I created my own custom soft keyboard on Android. How can I bind my custom keyboard for my application or for a specific EditText?

I can configure my custom keyboard in the Android settings, but I want to set the keyboard when my application starts.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do for bind my custom keyboard for my application or for an specific EditText?

You don't. Users are in control over their device, including what keyboard gets used.

> I can configure my custom keyboard in the setting of android, but i want to set the keyboard when my application start.

Fortunately, this is impossible, as it would be a significant security hole.